# Сохранение activity

Tags: android

Как в Android Studio сохранить прошлую активность? 
Вот мой код:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    configureBackButton();
}

private void configureBackButton() {
    Button backButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backButton);
    backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

Тут он финиширует эту активность, и возвращается к прошлой. Мне же нужно чтобы эта активность оставалась на паузе, а также возвращался к прошлой активность без пересоздания её.

Comment: Не финишируйте эту, но запускайте предыдущую.

Comment: Тогда выходит 1 > 2 > 1..